# Force HTTP over HTTPS in WEB API DotNet

Tags: .net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api controller and i need to consume it in a Java client but there is problems with the certificate so i need to work with HTTP not HTTPS.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{

    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            constraints : null,
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }
}


public class CommentAPIController : ApiController
{
    IItemService ise = new ItemService();
    ICategoryService ice = new CategoryService();
    // GET: api/CommentAPI
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Category> Get()
    {
        List<Category> list = new List<Category>();
        foreach (Category item in ice.getAllCategory())
        {

            list.Add(item);



        }
        return list;
    }
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Do you get any error when you call the url without 'https'?

Comment: No the page just keeps loading

Comment: And how do you host this app? Do you run it from Visual Studio, or is it already published on IIS?

Comment: I run it from visual studio

Comment: Please edit the properties of the web api project (right click on the project then properties, or expand the project content and double-click on the `Properties` group). Then navigate to the `Web` screen and see if your url points to `https`. If yes, please change it to `http://` and restart. Normally you have to force `https` by using `[RequireHttps]` attribute, so your issue seems the opposite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please edit the properties of the web api project (right click on the project then properties, or expand the project content and double-click on the Properties group).

Then navigate to the `Web` screen and see if any of your url points to `https`.

If yes, please change it to http:// and restart. Normally you have to force https by using `[RequireHttps]` attribute, so your issue seems the opposite.

According to our discussion in comments. Finally you have been providing wrong port for HTTPS service, which was in the exact screen I pointed you to.

Let's keep it here for the others.